# Pygame 1.9.2 for OS X Lion

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pygame

Hey im learning to program now so if you need to explain me something explain it a little bit easy so I can understand. Back to the problem in the book of O'Reilly "Head first Programing   using Python" tells me to download Pygame for Python 3.3 but its only aveliable for Windows.
How can I Install it on OS X Lion or do you know something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing from source [here](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src). There are instructions on the page for how to install.

Edit: Alternatively, you can follow the instructions [here](http://florian-berger.de/en/articles/installing-pygame-for-python-3-on-os-x).

Here are some commands to install pip:

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-0.7.2.tar.gz
tar xzf pip-0.7.2.tar.gz
cd pip-0.7.2
python setup.py install
```

Comment: I found it but don't understand it very much.

Comment: I added a link to a tutorial.

Comment: I Saw that one to when I type in the first line say error 404

Comment: Try this line instead: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"

Comment: IT WORKED THANK YOU SO MUCH I BEEN IN THIS FOR 2 WEEKS

Comment: Sorry but... how do i get pip?

Comment: try "brew install python" it should install pip as well

Comment: it download Python 2.7... Why?

Comment: it should include pip. if not, try the commands I added to the post

Comment: brew said that was unlinking of python Why?

Comment: I think because python was already installed. try the instructions in my answer for pip

Comment: homebrew should have most command line utilities. try brew install wget

Comment: /usr/local/share/python3/pip: No such file or directory

Comment: I just search it with the go to option and there isn't a folder called python3

Comment: did you try brew install wget ? after you install wget follow the instructions in the answer

Comment: ok... why when i call python it calls python2.7 and not python3

Comment: python 2.7 is the default version installed on macs. call python3 to run python 3

Comment: its says that theres no file or directory

Comment: /usr/local/share/python3/easy_install pip

Comment: is python 3 installed try just typing python3

Comment: python3 and what else?

Comment: just type python3 into terminal and see if it finds it

Comment: you can check this with pip --version

Comment: try this: sudo easy_install pip then check for pip again

Comment: returns error no url, filename, or requirements specified

Comment: did you try brew install python?

Comment: how do I download get-pip.py

Comment: right click and look for something like save link as

Comment: navigate in terminal to where you downloaded it (probably ~/Downloads) and run python get-pip.py then check if it is installed pip --version

Comment: it says ~/desktop is a directory

Comment: make sure you downloaded that file to Downloads then in terminal run cd ~/Downloads

Comment: ok i installed it but now it say that there sint a directory called /usr/local/share/python3/pip

Comment: I search it and just ahs /usr/local/share

Comment: after the cd ~/Desktop command run python get-pip.py to isntall pip

Comment: its installed but in /Libraries/Python2.7/site-packages

Comment: to install pip for python3 try python3 get-pip.py

Comment: /usr/local/share/python3/pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame this command returns no such file or directory

Comment: try just this pip install hg+bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame

Comment: and make sure pip is installed for python3

Comment: try brew install mercurial

Comment: unable to execute llvm-gcc-4.2: No such file or directory

error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

Comment: hg --version will tell you if it did

Comment: pip install hg+bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame

Comment: execption ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'hg+bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame', 'at', '+bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame')

Comment: http://dudeslife.com/blog/2014/programming/installing-python-3-3-3-pygame-on-os-x-mavericks/